# Image of a circle under $z\mapsto z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to describe the image of an arbitrary circle $re^{i\theta}+a+bi$ of radius $r>0$ and centre $a+bi$ in the complex plane under the map $z\mapsto z^2$. I have worked out the case for $a=b=0$ (we just get a circle of radius $r^2$) and the case $r=a$ or $r=b$, since this gives us a cardioid. But for the general case, I compute
$$
(re^{i\theta}+a+bi)^2=e^{i\theta}(r^2e^{i\theta}+2r(a+bi)+(a^2-b^2+2abi)e^{-i\theta})
$$
I am wondering what I can say about the image of a more general circle, and what it looks like.

Comment: For the case $a=b=0$ you should get a circle of radius $r^2$, not $\frac{1}{r^2}$.

Comment: Yes you are right of course, fixed it.

Comment: You can play around with it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dvybyssbhc). Looks like maybe a rotated cartioid.

Comment: Is there a general name for such a curve? It looks rather funny :)

Comment: [Limaçon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Limacon.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it’s a small-enough circle, far enough from the origin, it’ll get stretched to a slightly distorted circle, nothing cardioidy about it.

Comment: This is also no what I claimed